# I have Microsoft assembly name. How to find out the Dll name in which this assembly exists

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Microsoft assembly name and class name (Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous). How can I find out the name of Dll that this assembly resides.

I am instrumenting the performance of various dlls in App dynamics tool. I searched up and found ildasm.exe . But this is a disassembler of a DLL.

I want to know the dll. How can I know the name of the Microsoft Dll if I know one of the assembly name and class name in that dll?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Assembly.CodeBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.codebase) property will return the assembly's original location, even if it has been copied to a temporary location via [shadow copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/shadow-copies-and-shadow-copy-sets). You can use `typeof(TypeName).Assembly` to access the assembly. As a complete example:

`var dll = typeof(Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous).Assembly.CodeBase;`

The CodeBase property returns a string in a URI format, so you may want this instead to translate it to a regular path:

`var dll = new Uri( typeof(Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous).Assembly.CodeBase ).LocalPath;`

If shadow copying isn't a concern for you, you can use [Assembly.Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location) which is already a regular path.